# Grub not showing up while booting?

Tags: windows, kali-linux

I recently installed Kali Linux V2 in my PC with windows 10 already installed. But it when i tried booting up,it booted up with the usual windows 10 while the grub was supposed to show up.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will be assuming that `grub` didn't show up at all and that your system is still only booting into `Windows 10`.

If that is the case, I would first check the partition table to see it the drive was partitioned and `Linux` was actually installed on it or not.

If it isn't then you did something wrong. If it is and `grub` isn't showing up then `grub` was probably not installed on the boot partition of your drive. You have `two` options in this case.

- Option 1: Try reinstalling Kali and don't forget to choose `/dev/sda` as the place holder for `grub`.
- Option 2: `chroot` into the Linux system already installed and install `grub` to your `/dev/sda/`